# Characterize $\frac{df}{dx}(x)f(x)f(x)=x$

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

can you help me characterize $\frac{df}{dx}f(x)f(x)=x$? Should be 1st order, not-linear, not elliptic, parabolic, hyperbolic.

Solution with characteristics not possible because not (quasi)linear.

Any ideas for characterization/solution theory?

Thanks!

Comment: After editing, I realised that $*$ could have meant convolution instead of product. If you meant that, you can revert my edit, but also please add a note saying that it is convolution

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a separable ODE. Note that $f'f^2 = (f^3/3)'$. So just set $g=f^3/3$, then the equation is simply $g'=x$. We can solve by just integrating both sides
$$ g(x) = \frac{x^2}2 + C$$
i.e. the general solution is
$$ f(x)= \left(\frac{3x^2}2 + C\right)^{1/3}$$

Comment: This also amounts to just separating variables $y^2 dy = x dx$ and integrating both sides.

Comment: @Ned ah yes, separable ODE, that was the name I was looking for. Thanks!